# ionic3 get all data from firebase

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

[image]

How do I get all the posts from all the users displayed in my template? I cant think of a solution,I am a new to firebase and ionic3.
Could someone help me with a small snippet or code?

Answer (score 0):

From your service, just return the **`FirebaseListObservable`** to your component.

```
@Injectable()
export class ExpenseService {

    public users: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

   constructor(private afDB: AngularFireDatabase){
        this.users = this.afDB.list('/users');        
   }  

   getUsers() {
    return this.users ;
  }
}
```

and then,

```
constructor(private _service: YourService) {

  _service.getUsers()
    .subscribe(users=>{
        // do something...
    })
}
```

and use ngFor

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users | async">
    {{ user.displayName}}
</li>
```

Comment: I am using ionic3 with angular 4, I dont think FirebaseListObservable  is supported anymore.
Please refine the code for ionic3 and angular4 to get all the posts from database